# AngularJS --> Select requires to clicks to visually change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the following HTML and am having issues when a user selects from the dropdown box. The issue is that when you click the first time, you can see the variable change through a console log, but visually the item remains blank. If I select the item again, it will then visually show.

Here's my HTML>

```
<div class="section">
<select ng-model="companyInfo" ng-change='getCompany(companyInfo)' 
  ng-options="company.name for company in list">
</select><br>
</div>
```

I have a feeling its a real rookie mistake, but I can't figure it out!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT --

Thanks for the quick replies! Should have given getCompaniesList

```
$scope.getCompany = function(company) {
console.log("companyInfo passed", company);

internalClientService.getCompany(company.name)
.then(function(companyRecord){
  console.log("returning record from getCompany service", companyRecord); 
  $scope.currentCompany = companyRecord[0].name;
  $scope.currentCompanyId = companyRecord[0].companyid;
  getFarmList(companyRecord[0].farms);
});
```

};

```
var getFarmList = function(farmIdArray){
  $scope.farmsList = [];
  internalClientService.getFarms(farmIdArray)
   .then(function(farmNames){
    console.log('the farmNames returning', farmNames);
    for (var i = 0; i<farmNames.length; i++){
     $scope.farmsList.push(farmNames[i].name);
    }
  });
 };
```

The internalCLientService is a simple HTTP request.

What do you think?

Thanks,
B

Comment: I don't see any variable change here through `console.log`.

Comment: Could you show the getCompany method? Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GoYegrUjmoDafdMlvfam) out.

Comment: Hey Isborg, your plunker works. I guess that removes the HTML from being the culprit. Do you see anything wrong with the way I'm populating the farmslist? To give some color on the issue, the user will select a company and then the app grabs the farm data relating to that company. This list requires two clicks to visually change the data.

Comment: I figured it out. I was having a scope issue with the farmList. Thanks for the help fellas!